# aurelia: Attempted to register an Element when one with the same name already exists. Name: default

Tags: webpack, aurelia

```
Error: Attempted to register an Element when one with the same name already exists. Name: default.
    at register (http://localhost:8080/scripts/aurelia.bundle.js:12108:13)
    at ViewResources.registerElement (http://localhost:8080/scripts/aurelia.bundle.js:12211:5)
    at HtmlBehaviorResource.register (http://localhost:8080/scripts/aurelia.bundle.js:14788:16)
    at ResourceDescription.register (http://localhost:8080/scripts/aurelia.bundle.js:13862:19)
    at ResourceModule.register (http://localhost:8080/scripts/aurelia.bundle.js:13787:12)
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/aurelia.bundle.js:14171:28
```

I get this error when I try to require from a template:

```
<template>
    <require from="./components/todoList/todoList"></require>
    <todoList></todoList>
</template>
```

The rendering works fine when I append html instead:

```
<template>
    <require from="./components/todoList/todoList.html"></require>
    <todoList></todoList>
</template>
```

However, then functions declared in todoList.js do not work (... is not a function / undefined).

I use it within webpack. Here is my webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ProgressBarPlugin = require('progress-bar-webpack-plugin');
const JavaScriptObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');
const AureliaWebpackPlugin = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const isProductionBuild = process.argv.indexOf('-p') !== -1;

const plugins = [
  new ProgressBarPlugin(),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: ['aurelia'] }),
  new AureliaWebpackPlugin(),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: './src/index.html',
  }),
];

if (isProductionBuild) {
  const obfuscator = new JavaScriptObfuscator({
    compact: true,
    controlFlowFlattening: true,
    controlFlowFlatteningThreshold: 0.75,
    debugProtection: true,
    debugProtectionInterval: true,
    disableConsoleOutput: true,
    reservedNames: [],
    rotateStringArray: true,
    seed: 0,
    selfDefending: true,
    sourceMap: true,
    sourceMapBaseUrl: '',
    sourceMapFileName: '',
    sourceMapMode: 'separate',
    stringArray: true,
    stringArrayEncoding: true,
    stringArrayThreshold: 0.8,
    unicodeEscapeSequence: true,
  });

  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
  plugins.push(obfuscator);
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['./src/index'],
    aurelia: [
      'aurelia-bootstrapper-webpack',
      'aurelia-polyfills',
      'aurelia-pal',
      'aurelia-pal-browser',
      'aurelia-binding',
      'aurelia-dependency-injection',
      'aurelia-event-aggregator',
      'aurelia-framework',
      'aurelia-history',
      'aurelia-history-browser',
      'aurelia-loader',
      'aurelia-loader-webpack',
      'aurelia-logging',
      'aurelia-logging-console',
      'aurelia-metadata',
      'aurelia-path',
      'aurelia-route-recognizer',
      'aurelia-router',
      'aurelia-task-queue',
      'aurelia-templating',
      'aurelia-templating-binding',
      'aurelia-templating-router',
      'aurelia-templating-resources',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'scripts/[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'scripts/[name].bundle.js.map',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.p?css$/,
        include: /src/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?importLoaders=1',
          'postcss-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: /src/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
          'eslint-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        include: /src/,
        exclude: [path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), /(node_modules)/],
        use: 'html-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins,
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
  },
};
```

EDIT:

This is the current app structure:

app.html

```
<template>
    <require from="./components/todo-list/todo-list"></require>
    <todo-list></todo-list>
</template>
```

todo-list.html

```
<template>
    <h1>TODO List</h1>
    <input type="text" value.bind="newTodoTitle">
    <button click.trigger="addTodo()">test</button>
    <p repeat.for="todo of todos">
        ${todo}
    </p>
</template>
```

todo-list.js

```
export default class todoList {
  constructor() {
    this.newTodoTitle = '';
    this.todos = [];
  }

  addTodo() {
    this.todos.push(this.newTodoTitle);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are this has something to do with `<todoList></todoList>`. HTML is case-insensitive, so `todoList` gets converted to `todolist` before Aurelia can see, and thus Aurelia is looking for a class named `Todolist` and can't find it.

The easiest fix for this is to follow the standard naming conventions. Your filename doesn't really matter, but I'd name it `todo-list.js/html`. In `todo-list.js`, your class name will be `TodoList`, and then in the consuming template (`app.html` or whatever), you'll have

```
<template>
    <require from="./components/todoList/todo-list"></require>
    <todo-list></todo-list>
</template>
```

Let me know if this helps.

EDIT:

I now see the source of your problem:

`export default class todoList`

needs to become

`export class TodoList`

Aurelia VMs are not exported as default, and also you need to follow the naming convention.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not fix the problem. I added some additional information to the question

Comment: Great catch. eslint lured me into using a default export :) removing default fixes the issue. Thanks. You saved my day

Comment: Off topic: Funny coincident.. I am playing a random youtube playlist with aurelia videos and your presentation at JavaScriptWorld just came up

Comment: Ooh, what's the link to the video?